# results of jquery $.get assignment to variable not usable in event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can anyone identify the problem with this code and/or help to fix it?

I'm trying to preload html files, assign their html to variables, then inject them into a div after the user clicks a button.

I have it working successfully where the html files are loaded into the div on click, but I want to preload the html so the user doesn't have to wait for the external resource of the html file to load or not load if there is internet failure/ external resource fetching issues.

In the code, the alert successfully shows the html so I know at least that part works.

```
//IIFE
(function() { 

// ^other stuff omitted

// start navButton behavior


var hatContent;
function doSomethingWithData(data) {
  hatContent = data;
  alert(data);
}

$.get('helpAndTips.html', doSomethingWithData);

function replaceNotebookContentWithVariable(content){
    $("#usersNotebook").innerHTML = content;
  }

document.getElementById('helpAndTipsButton').addEventListener("click", function(){
  replaceNotebookContentWithVariable(hatContent);
 }, false);

// end navButton behavior ____________________X

// other stuff omitted

})(); // end IIFE
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it works better for you.

```js
(function() {
  //save the ajax deferred
  var helpAndTips = $.get('helpAndTips.html');

  function replaceNotebookContentWithVariable(content) {
    $("#usersNotebook").innerHTML = content;
  }

  $('#helpAndTipsButton').on("click", function() {
    //call the replace with the result of the deferred whenever it gets it
    //if the deferred has already resolved this will happen immediately
    helpAndTips.then(function(hatContent) {
      replaceNotebookContentWithVariable(hatContent);
    });
  }, false);
})();
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I tried your code sample and it did not work. I see your train of thought so I tried the following. Once again, the alert works, but the html content is not assigned to the div. 
     
`var helpAndTips = $.get('helpAndTips.html'); //$("#usersNotebook").innerHTML = helpAndTips; helpAndTips.then(function(data){ $("#usersNotebook").innerHTML = data; alert(data); })`

Comment: Veryify that `#usersNotebook` is a valid selector.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason `$('#usersNotebook').innerHTML = data;` does not work, but `document.getElementById('usersNotebook').innerHTML` does work.

I never really managed to use helpAndTips like a variable and I think that is because fetching its data executes later in terms of event order than the code where I want to use the variable. However @Taplar your suggestion of using jquery's .then to fire a function after the data is fetched allowed me to add the "on cick" event listener with the acquired data inside of that "done" function which ensures the data is available due to it's place in the event chain. So the following code is working for me. Thanks!

```
`// start navButton behavior

function replaceNotebookContentWithVariable(content) {
  document.getElementById('usersNotebook').innerHTML = content;
}

var helpAndTips = $.get('helpAndTips.html');

helpAndTips.then(function(data){

  document.getElementById('helpAndTipsButton').addEventListener("click", function(){
    replaceNotebookContentWithVariable(data);
   }, false);

})
// end navButton behavior ____________________X`
```